# How can I compare an image to identify a person in the image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition, face-recognition

Through webcam I'm capturing an image of the person in front. Then I display a video. After that I have to find out if its the same person standing in front. How can I do this? The possibilities in internet require many images to train an SVM. I only have one photo of the person to be recognized. How can I achieve this? Please provide with some code sample if possible as I'm new to this. I have already implemented the webcam logic. Just the image recognition I need.

Comment: This is a pretty had problem to accomplish. There are a few options you can try (but machine learning would probably be the best option). If you're certain you can only use one picture to check against you can try template maching. Opencv has some code on this at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html.

Comment: Template matching needs the exact same image. I tried it. When its the same person but different images, it can't identify. How do they do this for logins? They only get one webcam image and somehow they identify the person next time? how do they do it?

Comment: Yeah, that's definately a downfall of template matching. Differences can ruin the match. Big companies probably use Machine learning to match faces. But basically it boils down to how similar is this face to the one I want to match. You can find what features about a face are important find a metric to compare them and combine these feature metrics with a given weight. If the overall metric is greater than some threshold you've found a match.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, let's give this a try.

A fairly typical method is to use something called eigenfaces. OpenCV has a whole section on facial recognition using EigenFaces and similar approaches found at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

But this assumes you have a database of images to use (but it's not a bad place to start looking).

**Method using facial/image features:**

This method isn't necessarily all that efficient as it depends on how efficient your calculation of certain features is. And the accuracy of this method depends on how well you define your features and their weighting factors. But nonetheless it's a method that doesn't necessarily require any machine learning. (although it would certainly help!)

Another method is to try to compare how similar your source and target face are. This can be done by comparing a set of features.

The first thing you'll want to do is decide if the target image contains a face.
See
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html
or you can implement the Viola-Jones algorithm found [Here.](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/425/slides/13-ViolaJones.pdf)

Now, if your face detection algorithm doesn't already do this you'll want to find the orientation, scale, and position of your target face (this will be useful for finding certain features about a person face).

Now you'll need to calculate your target face's features.
You can use image features and descriptors like Fast, SIFT, and ORB to compute image features and compare.
see http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html

Or since you know your dealing with faces you can calculate features that can help distinguish people.
Examples being:

Distance between Eyes, face shape. Length of nose. Height of eyes. distance between nose and mouth, etc.

The tricky part is figuring out how to reliably calculate the feature metrics and then combine all of these into a single metric. Machine learning algorithms are generally employed to find weighting factors for combining each metric.

But you can use some guess work to pick initial weights and then do some trial and error until you find a set of weights that work for you.

Once you have the weights figured out you can combine them by finding the squared difference between the source and target features and add them all together. (this works best if all the subfeatures are normalized first (ie always in the range 0 to 1) and weighted so that the overall metric ranges from 0 to 1.

Lets say you have 5 features f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 all between 0 and 1
These values are the normalized squared difference between the source and target face.

and you have 5 weighting factors:   0.3, 0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.2  (sums up to 1)

your overall metric would be

```
Overall Metric = 0.3 * f0 + 0.1 * f2 + 0.15 * f3 + 0.25 * f4 + 0.2 * f5
```

Then the two faces are more similar if the value is closer to 0 and less similar if the value is closer to 1.  In the above example feature 0 is the most significant feature while feature 2 is the least.